# Преобразование массива объекта к массиву значений объекта

Tags: java

Есть класс:

```
public static class Car {
    private final String carId;
    private final String carName;

    public Car(String carId, String carName) {
        this.carId = requireNonNull(carId);
        this.carName = requireNonNull(carName);
    }

    public String getCarId() {
        return carId;
    }

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }
}
```

Есть `List` объектов `Car`. Хочу получить `ImmutableSet` полей `carName`. Причем `carName` у разных объектов может совпадать.
Делаю что-то подобное:

```
List<Car> cars = ...; 
ImmutableSet<String> carNames = cars.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getCarId().equals("1"))
            .map(item -> item.getCarName());
```

Как вы заметите, `.map` возвращает `Stream`.

Как получить `Set<String>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить `Set` можно так:

```
Set<String> carNames = cars.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getCarId().equals("1"))
            .map(item -> item.getCarName())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Тогда после этого:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

cars.add(new Car("1", "name_1"));
cars.add(new Car("1", "name_1"));
cars.add(new Car("1", "name_2"));
cars.add(new Car("2", "name_3"));
cars.add(new Car("3", "name_4"));
cars.add(new Car("4", "name_5"));

Set<String> carNames = cars.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.getCarId().equals("1"))
        .map(item -> item.getCarName())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(carNames);
```

На экран будет выведено:

```
[name_2, name_1]
```